# Configuration page of control panel portlet does not appear

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, control-panel

I've created a Liferay control panel portlet that works nicely.
Now I want to add a configuration page. I've done as follows:

1. Add config-template init-parameter to portlet.xml
2. Add configuration-action-class to the liferay-portlet.xml

But, the configuration menu does not appear:

[image: Configuration does not appear]

Here are the two descriptors.

**portlet.xml**

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>manage-apples-portlet</portlet-name>
    <display-name>Apple Management Admin</display-name>
    <portlet-class>de.apples.portlet.ManageApplesPortlet</portlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <name>config-template</name>
        <value>/html/manage-apples-portlet/config.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>view-jsp</name>
        <value>/html/manage-apples-portlet/view.jsp</value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <name>jsp-path</name>
        <value>/html/manage-apples-portlet/</value>
    </init-param>
    <expiration-cache>0</expiration-cache>
    <supports>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </supports>
    <resource-bundle>content.Language</resource-bundle>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
    <security-role-ref>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role-ref>
</portlet>
```

**liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>manage-apples-portlet</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <configuration-action-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultConfigurationAction</configuration-action-class>
    <control-panel-entry-category>content</control-panel-entry-category>
    <control-panel-entry-weight>10.0</control-panel-entry-weight>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <css-class-wrapper>manage-apples-portlet</css-class-wrapper>
</portlet>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first view, I don't see portlet modes in the support element, I think you should add

```
<portlet-mode>view</portlet-mode>
<portlet-mode>edit</portlet-mode>
```

inside supports element of portlet.xml.

Comment: Thank you. That worked!
(Sometimes you don't see the simple things.)